# How to split number and char

Tags: c, string, scanf

I want to assign char and numbers to variables. How can it be done with the `sscanf()` function?

```
char buffer[50]= "A123.4,B567.8,C901.2";

char a = << A;
char b = << B;
char c = << C;

double x = << 123.4;
double y = << 567.8;
double z = << 901.2;
```

Comment: First you need to [tokenize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) the input strings to get the individual comma-separated parts. Then it's just a question of using the correct indexing to get the character, and using e.g. [`strtod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) to get the value.

Comment: You could use `sscanf`: `sscanf(buffer, "%c%lf,%c%lf,%c%lf", &a, &x, &b, &y, &c, &z);`.

Answer (score 1):

use `sscanf`:

```
char buffer[50]= "A123.4,B567.8,C901.2";
char a, b, c;
double x, y, z;

sscanf(buffer, "%c%lf,%c%lf,%c%lf", &a, &x, &b, &y, &c, &z);
```

Comment: Checking the return value of `sscanf()` is useful too.

Comment: While this could potentially handle less than three inputs (if the result of `sscanf ` is checked) it will not be able to handle more than three inputs. And if the number of inputs become large it will become a mess rather quickly.